# Service invoked too many times in a short time: Calendar. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. Can the limit be increased?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, quota

So I am using a script that calculates multiple events destination using a reference postcode, using google maps. After certain number of uses I get the following message:

"Service invoked too many times in a short time: Calendar. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls."

My question is can the limit be increased?

Kindest

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) to suggest that  it is possible to stop simultaneous(almost) requests "rate limiting". As the error states the only way to avoid such errors is to `sleep` between calls. If the error was different, say,

> Service invoked too many times <strike>in a short time</strike>: Calendar

then it is possible to upgrade to a different gsuite edition to avail  upgraded quota/day(10k vs 5k calendar events/day)